# GAE flexible environment postgres connection string?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine

The sample code for connecting to postgres uses SQLAchemy. Is this required, or is there a way to specify the host in a conventional psycopg2 connection string? ("dbname=... host=... port=... etc"), avoiding SQLAlchemy.

I can access the db using cloud_sql_proxy just fine. I just can't get to it from a deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

What I had failed to do was to include the necessary settings in my app.yaml file:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]
```

That is, the short answer to my question is, “No you don’t have to use SQLAlchemy.”

**More Information**

The hostname, as documented in the sample app, is `/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]`

You can get `[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]` from the command line: "gcloud sql list" tells you your instance names, then "gcloud sql describe `[instance name]`" tells you lots about one instance, including its `connectionName`, the value of which is your `[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]`.

In my code I connect to either a local copy of the db or the cloud db when testing locally, depending on whether the `cloud_sql_proxy` is running or not. When deployed, the app accesses the cloud db. That’s all encapsulated in this function:

```
def pg_connect(str):
  """ Connect to local db, use proxy, or connect directly.
      If USE_LOCAL_DB is set, connect to that db locally (default user, etc.)
      Otherwise, use /cloudsql/... on port 5432, unless port 5431 is bound,
      in which case the proxy server is running, and the host is localhost
      on port 5431. (The proxy port number is specified when starting
      cloud_sql_proxy.)
  """
  dbname = os.environ.get('USE_LOCAL_DB')
  if dbname != None:
    return psycopg2.connect('dbname={}'.format(dbname))

  # Extract the dbname from the connection string and set up for deployed GAE
  # access.
  dbname = re.search('dbname=(\w*)', str).group(1)
  port = 5432
  host = '/cloudsql/...'
  user = '...'
  password = '...'
  # if port 5431 is bound, the proxy is running, and the connection string
  # refers to localhost on that port
  s = socket.socket()
  try:
    c = s.bind(('localhost', 5431))
  except:
    # Unable to bind: proxy must be running
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 5431
  s.close()
  conn_str = 'dbname={} host={} port={} user={} password={}'.format(
      dbname,
      host,
      port,
      user,
      password)
  return psycopg2.connect(conn_str)
```